# [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm creating a realtime map in laravel using VUE js. and the problem is my map isn't loaded in the server but it's loaded on my local server. in the console, it gives this message **[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: google is not defined**

**my component code is**

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>
                <button class="btn btn-success" @click="updateLocation">Update Position</button>
                <div class="card-body">

                    <div id="realtimemap" style="height: 412px; width: 100%;"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>

  export default{

    data(){

        return{
            map:null,
            marker:null,
            center:{lat: +10, lng: +10},
            data:null,
            lineCoordinates:[]
        }
    },

    methods:{

        mapInit(){


            this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('realtimemap'),{
                center: this.center,
                zoom: 8
            });

            this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: this.map,
                position: this.center,
                animation:"bounce",
            });
        },

        updateMap(){
            let newPosition = {lat:this.data.lat,lng:this.data.long};
            this.map.setCenter(newPosition);
            this.marker.setPosition(newPosition);

            this.lineCoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(newPosition.lat,newPosition.lng));

            var lineCoordinatesPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: this.lineCoordinates,
                geodesic: true,
                map: this.map,
                strokeColor: '#FF000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });
        },

        updateLocation(){

            let randomNumber=Math.random();

            let position={
                lat:10+randomNumber,
                long:10+randomNumber
            };

            axios.post('/api/map',position).then(response=>{
                console.log(response);
            })
        }

    },

    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.');
        this.mapInit();
    },
    created(){
        Echo.channel('location')
            .listen('SendLocation', (e) => {
                this.data=e.location;

                this.updateMap();
                console.log(e);
        });
    }
}
```

**my blade code is**

```
@extends("frontend.layouts.dashboard-layout")

@section("title","Realtime Map | Android Monitoring Dashboard")

@section("content")


<div id="page-wrapper">
<div class="main-page">
<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">

    <div class="content">
        <div class="title m-b-md" id="app">
            <example-component></example-component>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=******&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
  </div>
  </div>


 @endsection
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCGpt.png)

please help me

thanks in advance

Comment: you are `defer`ing the script. don't do that.

Comment: please explain your answer...

Comment: `defer` doesn't block things. so your script is likely running before the google library is included.

Comment: @DanielA.White thank you for your answer, now working fine...Thanks!